# Powershell regex matching various Serial numbers

Tags: regex, powershell, numbers, match

I am trying to create  regex that will match serial number for various devices.
the match is a mix of letters and numbers at least 6 characters long.
I am terrible with regex, all I have been able to get to work is `$Serial -match '\d\D'` but this does not verify the length.  I have tried `'\d{0-6}\D{0-6}'` but it does not get a match.
Could anyone provide an appropriate regex for serial numbers.  These are from different device types and all have a slightly different format.  Here is list of examples:

```
1VWPGF1
22P342Y4
2M251434B9
2TK95004x4
5CG934322D
8CG4322TVF
BRJ9323XR5
CND8432NVJ
MXL64322Q4
MXL64324MV
PF1CZ0EF
USE147SX0Y
USH7432L1W
```

Comment: `$serial -match '[a-z0-9]{6,}'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the following:

```
$Serial -match '[A-Z0-9]{6,}'
```

`[]` denotes a character class. Inside you have a range of characters `A` through `Z` and `0` through `9`. `{6,}` matches 6 or more times the current match (0-9 or A-Z). Normally `A-Z` is case sensitive in regex, but the `-match` operator is not. If you want uppercase matches only, I recommend changing to `-cmatch`, the case-sensitive variant.

Comment: Thank you that looks fine.  I just need something to make sure someone isn't specifying something general like workstation or hostname so that should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not worried about case-sensitivity or underscores, here's an even shorter version

```
$serial -match '[\w]{6,}'
```

It's not suitable if you might have underscores in the strings that you need to exclude.

Also, I recommend sites like https://regex101.com/ for testing your regexes. You can see the results real-time, and there are helpful syntax guides on the page.